# How can I make a html solution here instead of using a javascript hack?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a chat box (front end) for my website project.

You may test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ovdzaj2v/5/

Now, this current fiddle use javascript hack `pushChatUp()` function to move the messages. I don't like this hack because:

- It's ugly.
- It's hard to calculate how much up messages must go because they can
  be different sizes (overlap issues).

I want a HTML solution, but am not sure how to do it. For example, html elements stack below one another like:

```
<div id=top>
</div>
<div id=bottom>
</div>
```

How can I make this happen with `.messages`? So after javascript appends the message, `pushChatUp()` would not be needed.

JS:

```
function openChat(){
    document.getElementById("chatinput").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("chatbutton").style.display = "block";
    c = document.getElementById("chatbutton");
    i = document.getElementById("chatinput");
    cm = document.getElementById("chatmessage");
    c.innerHTML = "";
    c.style.height = "100%";
    c.style.background = "slategray";
    c.style.width = "350px";
    c.style.marginLeft = "20%";

    i.style.display = "block";
    c.style.display = "block";
}

function checkKey(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
    if(event.keyCode === 13){ //Enter
        i = document.getElementById("chatinput");
        sendChat(i.value);
        i.value = "";
    }
}

var clientChat = [];

function sendChat(text){
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = "chatmessage";

    div.innerHTML = text;

    div.style.display = "block";

    pushChatUp();

    clientChat[50] = div;

    document.getElementById('chat').appendChild(div);
}

function pushChatUp(){
    var correctOrder = [];
    var size = 0;
    for(var key in clientChat) {
        message = clientChat[key];
        key = Number(key) + 70;
        message.style.marginBottom = key.toString() + "px";
        correctOrder[key] = message;
        ++size;
        if(size > 28){
            correctOrder.splice(key, 1);
            message.style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('chat').removeChild(message);
        }
        lastMessageSize = message.innerHTML.length;
    }
    clientChat = correctOrder;
}
```

Comment: Please include your relevant JS in your question.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: um simply adding the data at the end would work ? http://jsbin.com/guguhowibo/edit?output

Comment: @Jonasw Hi, yes but I don't know how to do that while keeping position: fixed; on the message

Comment: @quad maybe dont use position:fixed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set `position: absolute` for each single message, while you - obviously - need them to be positioned *relative* to each other.

That being said, your actual problem is to align the messages vertically at the bottom of your chat window. My best guess for this is to use dynamically growing container, absolutely positioned at the bottom.

I've created a minified example below (without any chat capabilities, but you get the idea). You'll still have to scroll down using JS (`scrollTop()`), though.

```css
#chat {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #339;
  height: 150px;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.message {
  background: grey;
  margin: 4px;
  width: fit-content;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="message">Hello</div>
    <div class="message">Hi there</div>
    <div class="message">How are you? What are you doing?</div>
    <div class="message">Surfin' the web</div>
    <div class="message">Haha, me toooo :o)</div>
  </div>
  <input placeholder="I'm useless" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'll check this soon, looks promising. Thanks!